# What are receivers between 118 and 162 MHz called?

Tags: radio, receiver

I’m looking to get a receiver that covers the area between 118 and 162 MHz. Unfortunately all  I have found so far with “Air Band receiver” goes     to max 140 MHz.

Do they have a special name for those receivers?

Comment: You are looking a receiver for the two meter band.

Comment: The BaoFeng UV-5R Plus has a range from 136-174 MHz and 400-520 MHz. That's not your entire range. But it covers the higher frequency end of it and goes beyond the max you found. The lower end of your range is the VHF airband. Was divided into 25 kHz bands, but I think in Europe they are dividing that into 3 bands each (8.33 kHz) now. For US anyway, look up aviation transceivers, for example, to get that lower band. (Or receivers.) You haven't stated your requirements, though, for reception.

Answer (score 4):

Generically this is still called "VHF", though that also refers to Band II broadcast (aka FM) on 88-108 MHz, as well as air band, the 2m amateur band, and marine VHF (156-172 MHz).

What application are you thinking of that covers this range?

I would be searching for "VHF communications receivers".

It may be helpful to mention your geographic region. As far as I know, only the air band, the amateur 2m band, and the marine band are worldwide, there may be geographical limits on some other uses of these frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

The 144 MHz to 148 MHz amateur band is generally referred to as "the 2 metre band" because the central wavelength is approximately 2 metres. Given that 118 MHz has a wavelength of 2.54 metres and 162 MHz has a wavelength of 1.85 metres I would probably call it "an extended 2 metre band".

Answer (score 0):

A search using the term "VHF wideband receiver" will usually return radios covering your required frequency range (plus often a lot more).